# Link [lightbox] is not clickable on whole image

Tags: css, wordpress, image, hyperlink, lightbox

On page in section "CERTYFIKATY" I have image carousel. After click the image it displays lightbox. Problem is in some parts/areas of image - I can't click to open it in lighbox (especially in the middle). The whole image should linking.
What could be the reason?

Comment: The carousel back/forward controls have a higher z-index than the images. One way to address that is to add `div.flex-viewport { z-index: 202; }`

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much :)